# Using cout in bada

Tags: c++, bada

It dosent seem that iostream is in the directory for bada. 
is this right ? 
What should i use instead ? 
This file need me to use cout, in many forums i see that this function use in bada but i ca not find it in bada.
I use bada 1.2.0 and 1.2.1.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed AppLog, AppDebug and do forth are you primary options. If you need logging at runtime (ie Release) you are stuck for in-built options. I usually write a text file in a location I can access.

I don't know if copying iostream would work ... doubt it.

Answer (score 0):

`iostream` is not in the SDK for Bada.
If you want to log information from your app, you should use `AppLog()`.

If you would still want to use `iostream`copy a `iostream` from `mingw toolchain` or from another system that has `gcc toolchain`, `preferably Linux based` and then you can use `cout`.